# Make UITextField clear content each time return key pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm learning Swift by making a times tables app, which simply creates random times tables and asks the user to type the answer in a UITextField.

I'd like the user to be able to tap the return key and have the text field clear their previous answer and have the keyboard remain in view. I've already set up the other behaviour I want, it's just I can't seem to find any similar questions to figure out how to clear, and do all this when there return key is tapped.

Here's the code I have so far, which works when dismissing the keyboard, and doesn't clear the field.

Many thanks!

```
@IBAction func answerTyped(_ sender: UITextField) {

    /* Clear the text field*/

    questionNumber += 1
    attempted += 1
    markQuestion(answer: answer)
    newQuestion(awardLevel: currentLevel, questionNumber: questionNumber)
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about `clearsOnInsertion` and `clearsOnBeginEditing`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Comment: Thanks Matt, having found those after I did make good use of clearsOnBeginEditing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `textField` to be cleared on tapping <kbd>return</kbd> button you can use the `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
   textField.text = "" // Clears text
   //Do other things that you want to do when user taps return button
   return true
}
```

Note that this wont dismiss the `textField` like how you asked and usually users are used to dismissing their `textField` using <kbd>return</kbd>. So if you ask me this is **not good UX**. And you need to have a mechanism for the user to dismiss the keyboard if needed like tap outside to dismiss or something. So i hope you have that sorted out.

Your viewController should have implemented the `UITextFieldDelegate` for this method work.

```
class YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    var textField: UITextField! //Using IBOutlet or whatever

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesha, this helped me spot what my code was missing. And you're right about the dismissing feature: mine does dismiss properly!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to make something, likely your view controller containing this text field into a uitextfieldelegate, then add the necessary delegate functions.

I think the function you want is TextField:DidEndEditing:Reason https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/2352220-textfielddidendediting

Or you can just use

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   //delegate method
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true
}
```

which is called every time user hits the return key.  You would need to add your logic to clear the contents before the returns.